# Prometheus yaml file: did not find expected key

Tags: yaml, prometheus

I am new to the yml file formatting and I cannot figure out why when I run the application, I get the error:

> error loading config from \"prometheus.yml\": couldn't load
>   configuration (--config.file=\"prometheus.yml\"): parsing YAML file
>   prometheus.yml: yaml: line 34: did not find expected key

That is the only notification I get and there is nothing specific about it. This is what my file looks like:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']


global:
scrape_interval: 10s
evaluation_interval: 10s
- job_name: 'kafka'
  static_configs:
   - targets:
     - localhost:7071
```

Is my spacing causing the error? I tried duplicating the spacing like the default file. If I remove everything after the 2nd global, it runs. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have two "global" sections. The "scrape_interval" and the "evaluation_interval" parameters are already defined in the first "global", you don't need these definitions again at the end.

Comment: Is it just me or does Prometheus SUCK at error messages?